# Date time picker inside JTable

Tags: java, swing, datetime, date, jtable

Is it possible to add a DateTimePicker to a JTable Cell.A particular column should be updated with date and time..Is it possible to add such a component to a JTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. See this Swing Tutorial Track:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

Comment: -300 because the Tutorial does not mention any Editor for Date and Time; just a Renderer for a Date.

Comment: +1, yes the tutorial doesn't give a specific example of a date editor, but it does show how to use a color chooser as an editor. So the concept will be the same. All the OP has to do is find a Date editor that they like to use. There are many date editors floating around on the web.

Answer (score 4):

The [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) library includes three **TableEditor** classes. These classes allow the programmer to add a DatePicker, a TimePicker, or a DateTimePicker, to the cells of a Swing JTable (or to a SwingX JXTable).

Fair disclosure: I'm the primary developer.

The picker classes can also be added to normal swing panels or other swing containers.

Here is an example of how to add a DateTimePicker to your JTable:

```
// Create a table.
JTable table = new JTable(new DemoTableModel());

// Add the DateTimeTableEditor as the default editor and renderer for
// the LocalDateTime data type.
table.setDefaultEditor(LocalDateTime.class, new DateTimeTableEditor());
table.setDefaultRenderer(LocalDateTime.class, new DateTimeTableEditor());

// Explicitly set the default editor and renderer for column index 0.
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
column.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(LocalDateTime.class));
column.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(LocalDateTime.class));
```

I've pasted screenshot below of the table editor demo, the picker components, and the full demo. Note that the library includes a separate demo for the table editors. It's in the [Repository](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) under this folder: "LGoodDatePicker/Project/src/main/java/com/github/lgooddatepicker/demo/TableEditorsDemo.java".

The library can be installed into your Java project from the project [Release Page](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/releases).

The project home page is on Github at:
https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

.
[image: Table Editors Demo screenshot]

[image: Date and TimePicker screenshots]

[image: Full Demo screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [FLib-JCalendar](http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/examples.html) component as an CellEditor in a JTable.
(and post the working example here if you made it work)

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear if you found the component difficult to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'll need to implement both `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor`. As suggested by @Jens Schauder, the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) may be helpful. You might also look at this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) based [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) using `JCheckBox`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this code to set DatePicker in column 0:

```
    TableColumn dateColumn = YOURTABLE.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    dateColumn.setCellEditor(new DatePickerCellEditor());
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the premise of Jens link and applying that logic with the below link, you can add a date time picker into a JTable, just be careful, combining JCheckbox, JCombobox and the date time picker into a JTable the focus get a little messy, but i believe it can be solved with a focus listener, it will just take some time t implement.

I am currontly working on such a Table render-er with will incorperate it all, i will post it online when im done.

Link: [date and time picker in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053276/date-and-time-picker-in-java)