# date and time picker in JAVA

Tags: java, datetimepicker

I am looking for date and time picker, but found just JCalender that's for date picker and does not support the time

I also found this
http://matrex.sourceforge.net/help/DateTimePickerDialog.html

I like it because it is simple and easy to use, but I have no idea how to get it or where can I find it

Comment: Check this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing

Second answer has a full example

Comment: I also found DateTimePickerDialog interesting, so I searched for its implementation. It's here: http://sourceforge.net/p/matrex/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/matrex/matrex/gui/util/DateTimePickerDialog.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this thread (uses swingx `JXDatePicker` component, he extends it's functionality)

[Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing)

Second answer has a full example

download swingx from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingxjar.htm

example from the other post:

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.calendar.SingleDaySelectionModel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DateTimePicker extends JXDatePicker {
    private JSpinner timeSpinner;
    private JPanel timePanel;
    private DateFormat timeFormat;

    public DateTimePicker() {
        super();
        getMonthView().setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
    }

    public DateTimePicker( Date d ) {
        this();
        setDate(d);
    }

    public void commitEdit() throws ParseException {
        commitTime();
        super.commitEdit();
    }

    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setTimeSpinners();
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getLinkPanel() {
        super.getLinkPanel();
        if( timePanel == null ) {
            timePanel = createTimePanel();
        }
        setTimeSpinners();
        return timePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTimePanel() {
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        newPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //newPanel.add(panelOriginal);

        SpinnerDateModel dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
        timeSpinner = new JSpinner(dateModel);
        if( timeFormat == null ) timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance( DateFormat.SHORT );
        updateTextFieldFormat();
        newPanel.add(new JLabel( "Time:" ) );
        newPanel.add(timeSpinner);
        newPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return newPanel;
    }

    private void updateTextFieldFormat() {
        if( timeSpinner == null ) return;
        JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) timeSpinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
        DefaultFormatterFactory factory = (DefaultFormatterFactory) tf.getFormatterFactory();
        DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter) factory.getDefaultFormatter();
        // Change the date format to only show the hours
        formatter.setFormat( timeFormat );
    }

    private void commitTime() {
        Date date = getDate();
        if (date != null) {
            Date time = (Date) timeSpinner.getValue();
            GregorianCalendar timeCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            timeCalendar.setTime( time );

            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeCalendar.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) );
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCalendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) );
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
            setDate(newDate);
        }

    }

    private void setTimeSpinners() {
        Date date = getDate();
        if (date != null) {
            timeSpinner.setValue( date );
        }
    }

    public DateFormat getTimeFormat() {
        return timeFormat;
    }

    public void setTimeFormat(DateFormat timeFormat) {
        this.timeFormat = timeFormat;
        updateTextFieldFormat();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Date Time Picker");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
        dateTimePicker.setFormats( DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance( DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM ) );
        dateTimePicker.setTimeFormat( DateFormat.getTimeInstance( DateFormat.MEDIUM ) );

        dateTimePicker.setDate(date);

        frame.getContentPane().add(dateTimePicker);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you MihaiC, can you give me an example how to use this?

Comment: the second answer has code to extend the component. I have not tested this. edited answer to include it.

Comment: thanks a lot MihaiC, I did use jCalendar http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/screenshots.html it's much easier, and I fixed some codes in your code but it's working 100%

Comment: glad to hear it :) good luck with your project

Comment: thank you so much MihaiC, I still have a lot of questions but I already asked you many :) thanks again

Comment: Hi MihaiC, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337800/java-timer-countdown-jtable

Answer (score 2):

The [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) library includes a good **DateTimePicker** component. This component allows the user to edit both the date and the time. The time can be edited with optional "spinner" style buttons, with the default "time list" button, or with both.

Fair disclosure: I'm the primary developer.

The DatePicker and the TimePicker classes can also be used individually, if desired.
I've pasted a screenshot of the three components below, (and the demo application).

The library can be installed into your Java project from the project [release page](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/releases).

The project home page is on Github at:
https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

[image: DateTimePicker screenshot]
[image: Demo screenshot]